# ¿Como puedo evaluar si un número está 5 veces por encima del que estoy buscando en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

espero se encuentren muy bien. Estoy intentando hacer un juego sencillo en C#. Consiste en adivinar un número y darle pistas al usuario. Ejemplo si el usuario está 5 números por encima o 5 números por debajo del que se está buscando que le diga que está muy caliente, y si son 10 números, por encima o por debajo del que se está adivinando le diga que está caliente, así sucesivamente. Pero estoy trancado en los condicionales, creía que esta era la forma de indicar si está x números por debajo o por encima pero no está haciendo la función. No sé si esta sería la forma correcta. He aquí mi código. ¿Alguien me puede iluminar? Se los agradecería.

```
using System;

namespace Juego_Random
{
    class Program
    {
        static Random ranNumber = new Random();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bienvenidos a Adivinando el número escondido, se generá un número aleatorio y debe indicar cuál es.\n" +
                "Solo tienes 10 oportunidades.");
            Menu();
        }


        public static void Menu()
        {
            int attempsCounter = 1, numberToRead, opportunities = 10;
            

            int numberToPredit = Convert.ToInt32(ranNumber.Next(100) + 1);//RANDOM NUMBER

            Console.WriteLine( "Número aleatorio " + numberToPredit );//PRUEBA
            

            while ( attempsCounter <= opportunities )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n¿Cuál es el número generado?");
                numberToRead = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                if (numberToRead == numberToPredit)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Felicidades.! Adivinaste el número escondido. El número escondido es " + numberToPredit);

                }
                else if ( numberToRead > (numberToPredit + 5))//80
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nEstás muy caliente sigue intentando. Lo lograrás.! Te quedan " + (opportunities - attempsCounter));
                    ///Console.WriteLine("\n¿Cuál es el número generado?");
                    //numberToRead = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                else if ( numberToRead > (numberToPredit + 10) )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nTe estás acercando. Concentrate para que lo logres.! Te quedan " + (opportunities - attempsCounter));
                    //Console.WriteLine("\n¿Cuál es el número generado?");
                    //numberToRead = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                else if ( numberToRead > (numberToPredit + 30) )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nEstás frío. No te rindas tú puedes.! Te quedan " + (opportunities - attempsCounter));
                    //Console.WriteLine("\n¿Cuál es el número generado?");
                    //numberToRead = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                else if ( numberToRead > (numberToPredit + 50) )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nLo siento pero estás muy frío. :( Te quedan " + (opportunities - attempsCounter));
                    //Console.WriteLine("\n¿Cuál es el número generado?");
                    //numberToRead = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }

                attempsCounter++;
            }

        }
        

    }
}
```

Comment: Coloque una respuesta a tu pregunta, pruebala y me dices si te resultó util.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sucede en tú codigo que de la forma que lo has implementado solo se podran cumplir dos opciones la primera condicional `if (numberToRead == numberToPredit)` o se cumplira la segunda `if ( numberToRead > (numberToPredit + 5))` ya que esta condición es excluyente para las demas a continuación, ya que si es mayor que 10, que 30 y que 50, tambien será mayor que 5 y solo se cumplira esa condición que está primero en el orden de ejecución; ademas sucede en tu código que si el valor es menor que el valor oculto, no ocurrira ninguna opción, solo se incrementará `attempsCounter` en uno. Lo más aconsejable es verificar que el valor absoluto de la diferencia entre ambos números sea menor que el valor prefijado. Te dejo a continuación el codigo implementando lo que te explico.

```
using System;

namespace Juego_Random
{
    class Program
    {
        static Random ranNumber = new Random();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bienvenidos a Adivinando el número escondido, se generá un número aleatorio y debe indicar cuál es.\n" +
                "Solo tienes 10 oportunidades.");
            Menu();
        }

        public static void Menu()
        {
            int attempsCounter = 1, numberToRead, opportunities = 10;

            int numberToPredit = Convert.ToInt32(ranNumber.Next(100) + 1);//RANDOM NUMBER

            Console.WriteLine( "Número aleatorio " + numberToPredit );//PRUEBA. Esta linea deberas eliminarla despues de optimizar bien tu código

            while ( attempsCounter <= opportunities )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n¿Cuál es el número generado?");
                numberToRead = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (numberToRead == numberToPredit)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Felicidades.! Adivinaste el número escondido. El número escondido es " + numberToPredit);
                }
                else if ( Math.Abs(numberToRead - numberToPredit) < 5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nEstás muy caliente sigue intentando. Lo lograrás.! Te quedan " + (opportunities - attempsCounter));
                }
                else if ( Math.Abs(numberToRead -numberToPredit)< 10) )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nTe estás acercando. Concentrate para que lo logres.! Te quedan " + (opportunities - attempsCounter));
                }
                else if ( Math.Abs(numberToRead -numberToPredit )< 30) )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nEstás frío. No te rindas tú puedes.! Te quedan " + (opportunities - attempsCounter));
                }
                else if ( Math.Abs(numberToRead -numberToPredit)< 50) )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nLo siento pero estás muy frío. :( Te quedan " + (opportunities - attempsCounter));
                }
                else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nLo siento pero estás demasiado frío. :( Te quedan " + (opportunities - attempsCounter));
                }
                attempsCounter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias, de verdad que sí. Esto solucionó el problema por completo.

Comment: @Josias Me complace que te haya servido mi respuesta, por nada, estamos aquí para ayudar. Solo decirte que si te parece justo, me gustaria que marcaras la respuesta como aceptada y que le asignaras un punto, si crees que la respuesta sea merecedora de ello.